# Array is too big error in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code in python:

```
from numpy import *
import itertools

m, n  = 6, 10
set_m = [i + 1 for i in range(m + 1)]
comb  = zeros(((m + 1) ** n, n), dtype=int)

k = 0
for i in itertools.product(set_m, repeat=n):
    comb[k][:] = i
    k += 1
```

But when I run it, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    comb = zeros(((m + 1) ** n, n), dtype=int)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you really want 2 billion elements, `((m + 1) ** n)*n`?

Comment: Yes, sure. You are trying to create an array of integers with size (282475249, 10), which not surprisingly is too big.

Comment: Are you using the 64 bit version of Python? How much memory does your machine have?

Comment: I have python 32 bit and I have 16GB of memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure you MUST have a billion element array, and there is no way around it whatsoever (sometimes happens, but not every day), you can use  [memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to create the array in the hard drive instead of the RAM memory. But I think it would be wise to search for ways to re-write your code to avoid doing such a slow thing.